# HighCharts: Can I call the Exporting functions directly?

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to call the HighCharts Exporting module functions directly?  I'd like to have a button elsewhere on the page that can call the 'downloadPNG', 'downloadJPEG' etc functions that are usually called from the exporting contextButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just need to use `exportChart` method, for example:

```
chart.exportChart({
    type: 'image/png'
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0mLy6du3/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#exportChart